# Which one is the correct series expansion?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, power-series

Is

$$p^{n+1} = p^0+p^1+ \dots + p^n$$

or

$$p^{n+1} = p^0\times p^1\times \dots \times p^n\text{ ?}$$

I am confused.

please explain the correct one.

Comment: They are both wrong, as you will see if you take, say, $p=2$ and $n=3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;\;\;1+q+q^2+\ldots+q^n=\frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}\\\bullet\bullet&\;\;\;\;1+2+\ldots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}2\\\bullet\bullet\bullet&\;\;\;a\cdot a^2\cdot\ldots\cdot a^n=a^{1+2+\ldots+n}\end{align*}$$

Comment: Am i correct that $p^{n+1} = p \times p^n = p × \dots \times p$ [(n+1) times].

Comment: Yes, you are, since $\,p^n=p\cdotp\cdot\ldots\cdot p\,\,\,( n\,$ times )

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$a^m\cdot a^n=a^{m+n}$$

and $$\sum_{0\le m\le n}ar^m=\frac{a(r^{m+1}-1)}{r-1}$$

Now, judge yourself

Answer (score 0):

None of them. $p^{n+1} = p \times p^n = p × \dots \times p$ (n times).

Comment: is it n times or (n+1) times ?

Comment: @tree It's n times for multiplication, and (n+1) instances of the p symbol.